# How to insert data dynamically in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, insert, phpmyadmin

I need to record the date each event happens. I have this table.

[Click here to view the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwmBH.png)

NULL spaces are available to save a new date.
The X represents the date that the event occurred.

The problem is I do not know how to update the date each event occurs

I need to know the best option if you use INSERT or UPDATE querys.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Are you using DATETIME() columns? Do you have any particular code we can look at?

Comment: You are better off saving event dates in a detail table.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to update a column in a table with the current time:

```
UPDATE `yourtable` SET `yourcolumn` = NOW() WHERE `ID` = yourid
```

Assuming your columns are `DATETIME()` columns.

As an aside, it's best to have event-related information in another relationship table. This way you can link multiple events for each row in your main table. This provides a more accurate data-trail for accounting purposes (or in other words, you can see each and every update without overwriting anything).

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeking to have a 'last_modified' column on your table to help you keep track of changes made on your records, you should do this:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
ADD last_modified TIMESTAMP 
    DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
    ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Basically what it does is to add a 'last_modified' column, Set it to be a timestamp and make it to be updated with the current timestamp when there is an update on the record.